# Exponential form of tick marks for log plot in Mathematica

Tags: logging, plot, wolfram-mathematica

In an attempt to learn more Mathematica, I am trying to reproduce the tick marks on this [log (log) plot](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stirling%27s_Approximation.svg):
[image]

This is as close as I can get:

```
LogLogPlot[Log[x!], {x, 1, 10^5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, Ticks -> {Table[10^i, {i, 0, 5}], Table[10^i, {i, -1, 6}]}]
```

[image]

## Question

How can I make tick marks that are always of the form 10^n for appropriate values of n?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Superscript`, the generic typesetting form without any built-in meaning, is your friend for this.

```
LogLogPlot[Log[x!], {x, 1, 10^5}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
   Ticks -> {
       Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i]}, {i, 0, 5}], 
       Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i]}, {i, -1, 6}]
       }
   ]
```

Comment: You should be having a relaxed weekend after this busy conference week! I couldn't find you to say goodbye, yesterday. I was invited for dinner.

Comment: Thanks! I know about Superscript[], but I didn't think to pair up the value 10^i with its presentation Superscript[10,i].

Comment: @Sjoerd Well at least I'm checking SO from home, not while visiting a foreign country. ;-)  (I know, have to keep the consecutive days count going..)

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the previous answers, you can calculate the right range for the `Table`s in the `Ticks` option automatically by doing something like

```
ticksfun[xmin_, xmax_] := 
 Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i]}, {i, Floor[Log10[xmin]], 
   Ceiling[Log10[xmax]]}]

LogLogPlot[Log[x!], {x, 1, 10^5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
 Ticks -> {ticksfun, ticksfun}]
```

Answer (score 3):

[`LevelScheme`](http://wnsl.physics.yale.edu/levelscheme/) is a package for Mathematica that makes making such plots very easy, fully customizable and professional looking. I'm very certain that if your plot was made in mathematica, it was using LevelScheme. Here's my reproduction of your plot in Mathematica using `LevelScheme`

```
<<LevelScheme`;
Figure[{
    FigurePanel[{{0,1},{0,1}},
            PlotRange->{{0,5},{-1,6}},
            FrameTicks->{
                        LogTicks[0,5,ShowMinorTicks->False],
                        LogTicks[-1,6,ShowMinorTicks->False]
                    }
    ],
    RawGraphics[
        LogLogPlot[{Log[x!],x Log[x]-x},{x,1,10^5},
                PlotRange->{{0,10^5},{10^-1,10^6}},
                PlotStyle->Darker/@{Red,Green}
            ]
    ]
}, PlotRange->{{-0.1,1.04},{-0.05,1.025}},ImageSize->300{1,1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have to admit I haven't started using LevelScheme yet (except for a a few plots), but the explicit `PlotRange->{{-0.1,1.04},{-0.05,1.025}}` looks really nasty.  This is the kind of thing that's annoying in working with Mathematica graphics.  Is there a way around it, to just show the full plot area (which is already defined by the frame)?

Comment: @Szabolcs I haven't looked into the internals of LevelScheme yet to see how they handle it. However, I think the need to define things explicitly is by-design in LevelScheme. I don't use it for quick plots or when I'm still working on the plots. I use it only in the final stages for the paper and spend time making it look pretty. It treats the figure as a square from `{0,0}` to `{1,1}` and the adjustments from that are to accommodate the tick marks. But you're right: it is logical that an `Automatic` option should be there which snaps to the outer most non-white pixel.

Comment: Not sure if that is a trivial task though, because the outermost pixel will depend on the aspect ratio used in `ImageSize` and I remember an answer here that tried to guess the size to do a fit by `Rasterize`ing it, finding the extreme, etc. But surely something to think about

Comment: @Szabolcs BTW, using LevelScheme with 2D graphics (`ArrayPlot`, `DensityPlot`, etc) is very cumbersome and often buggy. It overlays the image directly on top of the figure instead if inside the bounding box and that makes it harder to do finer control...

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the label for a given tick, by giving a 2-tuple of `{value, label}` instead of giving just giving a `value`.

This still leaves us with the conundrum of how to maintain the `10^n`-form.
To do this, we observe, that using [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html) makes the `10^i` retain its form. However, we still need to [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html) the `i` inside of it, as otherwise we just get a bunch of `10^i`-labels.

Example:

```
In[19]:= Table[10^i, {i, 0, 6}]

Out[19]= {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000}

In[18]:= Table[10^Defer[i], {i, 0, 6}]

Out[18]= {10^i, 10^i, 10^i, 10^i, 10^i, 10^i, 10^i}

In[17]:= Table[10^Defer[Evaluate[i]], {i, 0, 6}]

Out[17]= {10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6}
```

Using this, we can now do the following to get a solution:

```
LogLogPlot[Log[x!], {x, 1, 10^5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate [i]]}, {i, 0, 5}], 
   Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate [i]]}, {i, -1, 6}]}, 
 TicksStyle -> StandardForm]
```

Comment: It's due to `TicksStyle -> StandardForm`.  You can also consider `HoldForm` instead of `Defer` (which has a more complex behaviour).